# Dump Python dictionary to JSON file

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, dump

I want to dump data that i scrapped into a json file. I believe it already is in a good format (dictionary, list, string, etc.) How can I output into a json file?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#weather.scraper

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import json

    def main():
        """weather scraper"""
        r = urllib.urlopen("https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KPHL/2016/1/1/MonthlyHistory.html?&reqdb.zip=&reqdb.magic=&reqdb.wmo=&MR=1").read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")
        tables = soup.find_all("table", class_="responsive airport-history-summary-table")

    scrapedData = {}
    for table in tables:
        print 'Weather Philadelphia'

        for tr in table.find_all("tr"):
            firstTd = tr.find("td")
            if firstTd and firstTd.has_attr("class") and "indent" in firstTd['class']:
                values = {}
                tds = tr.find_all("td")
                maxVal = tds[1].find("span", class_="wx-value")
                avgVal = tds[2].find("span", class_="wx-value")
                minVal = tds[3].find("span", class_="wx-value")
                if maxVal:
                    values['max'] = maxVal.text
                if avgVal:
                    values['avg'] = avgVal.text
                if minVal:
                    values['min'] = minVal.text
                if len(tds) > 4:
                    sumVal = tds[4].find("span", class_="wx-value")
                    if sumVal:
                        values['sum'] = sumVal.text
                scrapedData[firstTd.text] = values

    print scrapedData

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the following:

```
with open('output.json', 'w') as jsonFile:
    json.dump(scrapedData, jsonFile)
```

Where is going to write the dictionary to the `output.json` file in the working directory.
You can provide full path like `open('C:\Users\user\Desktop\output.json', 'w')` instead of `open('output.json', 'w')` for example to output the file to the user's Desktop.

Comment: great thank you! do you also know how i can specify where to save it? Now, it automatically saves it to my documents.

Comment: @malina I have edited my answer. Please let me know if that fixed your problem.