# Dump dictionary to json file as UTF-8

Tags: python, json, encoding, character-encoding

I want to dump a dictionary to file, like in [Dump Python dictionary to JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36601024/dump-python-dictionary-to-json-file). But I faced with a problem with encoding:
When I simply do

```
print(data)
```

I get something like this in terminal:

```
{'legend': '\n\r\n\t\tНа прямой расположены стойла, в которые необходимо расставить коров так, чтобы минимальное расcтояние между коровами было как можно больше.\r\n    \n', 'input_specification': '\n\r\n     Входные данные\r\n    \n\r\n\t\tВ первой строке вводятся числа N\xa0 (2 < N  < 10001) – количество стойл и K\xa0 (1 < K < N ) – количество коров. Во второй строке\xa0задаются N натуральных чисел в порядке возрастания – координаты стойл (координаты не превосходят 109)\r\n    \n', 'output_specification': '\n\r\n     Выходные данные\r\n    \n\r\n\t\tВыведите одно число – наибольшее возможное допустимое расстояние.\r\n    \n'}
```

So it is normal, human-readable text. But when I dump the same dictionary to some json file this way:

```
with open('Data\{0}.json'.format(i), 'w') as file:
        json.dump(data, file)
```

There is strange mess of special characters in the file:

```
{"legend": "\n\r\n\t\t\u041d\u0430 \u043f\u0440\u044f\u043c\u043e\u0439 \u0440\u0430\u0441\u043f\u043e\u043b\u043e\u0436\u0435\u043d\u044b \u0441\u0442\u043e\u0439\u043b\u0430, \u0432 \u043a\u043e\u0442\u043e\u0440\u044b\u0435 \u043d\u0435\u043e\u0431\u0445\u043e\u0434\u0438\u043c\u043e \u0440\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0442\u0430\u0432\u0438\u0442\u044c \u043a\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0432 \u0442\u0430\u043a, \u0447\u0442\u043e\u0431\u044b \u043c\u0438\u043d\u0438\u043c\u0430\u043b\u044c\u043d\u043e\u0435 \u0440\u0430\u0441c\u0442\u043e\u044f\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u043c\u0435\u0436\u0434\u0443 \u043a\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u043c\u0438 \u0431\u044b\u043b\u043e \u043a\u0430\u043a \u043c\u043e\u0436\u043d\u043e \u0431\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0448\u0435.\r\n    \n", "input_specification": "\n\r\n     \u0412\u0445\u043e\u0434\u043d\u044b\u0435 \u0434\u0430\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0435\r\n    \n\r\n\t\t\u0412 \u043f\u0435\u0440\u0432\u043e\u0439 \u0441\u0442\u0440\u043e\u043a\u0435 \u0432\u0432\u043e\u0434\u044f\u0442\u0441\u044f \u0447\u0438\u0441\u043b\u0430 N\u00a0 (2 < N  < 10001) \u2013 \u043a\u043e\u043b\u0438\u0447\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0432\u043e \u0441\u0442\u043e\u0439\u043b \u0438 K\u00a0 (1 < K < N ) \u2013 \u043a\u043e\u043b\u0438\u0447\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0432\u043e \u043a\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0432. \u0412\u043e \u0432\u0442\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0439 \u0441\u0442\u0440\u043e\u043a\u0435\u00a0\u0437\u0430\u0434\u0430\u044e\u0442\u0441\u044f N \u043d\u0430\u0442\u0443\u0440\u0430\u043b\u044c\u043d\u044b\u0445 \u0447\u0438\u0441\u0435\u043b \u0432 \u043f\u043e\u0440\u044f\u0434\u043a\u0435 \u0432\u043e\u0437\u0440\u0430\u0441\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f \u2013 \u043a\u043e\u043e\u0440\u0434\u0438\u043d\u0430\u0442\u044b \u0441\u0442\u043e\u0439\u043b (\u043a\u043e\u043e\u0440\u0434\u0438\u043d\u0430\u0442\u044b \u043d\u0435 \u043f\u0440\u0435\u0432\u043e\u0441\u0445\u043e\u0434\u044f\u0442 109)\r\n    \n", "output_specification": "\n\r\n     \u0412\u044b\u0445\u043e\u0434\u043d\u044b\u0435 \u0434\u0430\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0435\r\n    \n\r\n\t\t\u0412\u044b\u0432\u0435\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0435 \u043e\u0434\u043d\u043e \u0447\u0438\u0441\u043b\u043e \u2013 \u043d\u0430\u0438\u0431\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0448\u0435\u0435 \u0432\u043e\u0437\u043c\u043e\u0436\u043d\u043e\u0435 \u0434\u043e\u043f\u0443\u0441\u0442\u0438\u043c\u043e\u0435 \u0440\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0442\u043e\u044f\u043d\u0438\u0435.\r\n    \n"}
```

I tried to specify *ensure_ascii=False* like here: [Python Saving JSON Files as UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16291358/python-saving-json-files-as-utf-8), but it throws UnicodeEncodeError:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 11-12: character maps to <undefined>
```

All in all, how can I dump dictionary to JSON file without messing up with encoding?

Comment: What version of Python do you use?

Comment: @handras 3.7.2 32bit

Comment: How are u using `ensure_ascii = False `?

Comment: The "mess" is valid JSON using Unicode escape codes.  It's just not as readable.  When you read it back in it will be correct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to open the file specifying the file encoding.

```
with open('Data{0}.json'.format(1), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    json.dump(data, file, ensure_ascii=False)
```

This way I have dumped your example data sucessfully.

Comment: `encoding = 'utf-8'` is not necessary because the file reading and writing is all done as utf8 by default in Python 3 `open()` @handras

Comment: @skaul05 No, [`open` uses `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), which depends on the OS and terminal configuration.  It's better to be explicit and specify the encoding.  Not all Linux are correctly configured for UTF-8, and the Windows terminal doesn't use it, although some Python IDEs do.